# Android Arabic date display in TextView

Tags: java, android, date, arabic, simpledateformat

I am having problem in displaying arabic date in TextView. My code is as follows

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ar", "KW");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd-MMMM-yy");
Date currDate = new Date();

String formattedDate = sdf.format(currDate);
txtDate.setText(formattedDate);
```

It shows following output **(arabic date problem image)**:

[image]

But I need date as per SimpleDateFormat pattern `E, dd-MMMM-yy` in Arabic.
What should I do ?

Comment: BTW, "الإثنين" should be written as "الاثنين" because of "الأسماء العشرة"  Arabic grammar rule :)

Answer (score 2):

Arabic Language is not supported in the virtual device. Try your program on a real device (It should have Android 2.3 OS or more on it).

Comment: I have tested on Samsung Galaxy S. I don't know why, but it show me same output as in emulator.

Comment: @KevinAdesara Does it have Android 2.3 OS or more?

Answer (score 2):

Try This...

```
public static String parseDateToddMMyyyy(String time) {
    String inputPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    String outputPattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";

    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern,
            Locale.ENGLISH);
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern,
            Locale.ENGLISH);

    Date date = null;
    String str = null;

    try {
        date = inputFormat.parse(time);
        str = outputFormat.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [***issue***](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36689) raised in googleCodes.

this problem appear just in android 4.x; i tried in android 2.x in Arabic phone language and there is no problem